# JQGrid continue to load even if hidden

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using JQGrid in my solution in which i load tabs dynamically, but if i have a grid on a hidden tab the JQGrid does not seem to load properly and you have to wait for it to load completely before hiding it.

is there any way of continuing loading the grid even if it is not displayed on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `datatype: 'local'` *at the initialization* for all grids of the tabs which are not active. It will prevent grid to be loaded. You should change `datatype` to `'local'` (with respect of $('#gridId').jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype: 'json'})) and call `.trigger('reloadGrid')` inside of `select` callback of the jQuery UI Tabs or inside of `'tabsselect'` event handler.

You can optimize reloading of the grid which already has the `datetype: 'json'` (or 'xml') by querying the current `datetype` before resetting of `datatype` and reloading. To do this you should just get the current `datetype` with respect of `$('#gridId').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'datatype')`.